# Django. Как получить переменную, переданную в template из view в другой view?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно передать `num1` из `first_game` в `checking_game_answer`. Как это сделать?

Вот `views.py`:

```
def first_game(request):
    num1 = generate_number()
    return render(request, 'first_game.html', context={"num1": num1})


def checking_game_answer(request):
    rounds = 0
    while rounds < MAX_ROUNDS:
        answer = AnswerForm()
        answer = request.POST.get("answer")
        answer = {"answer": answer}
        correct_answer = get_correct_answer(num1)
        if answer == correct_answer:
            rounds += 1
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/first_game")
        else:
            return HttpResponse(render(request, "game_abort.html", context={"correct_answer":correct_answer, "answer": answer}))
    return HttpResponse(render(request, "game_congrats.html"))
```

Вот `first.game.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        {% block title %}    
        first_game
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Answer "yes" if the number is even, otherwise answer "no".</p>


    <form method = "POST" action="checking_game_answer/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            <label>Введите ответ</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="answer" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Продолжить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

get_correct_answer

```
def get_correct_answer(num1):   # проверяем число на чётность
    return "yes" if (num1 % 2 == 0) else "no"
```

def generate_number():

```
return random.randint(2, 30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Классика. Пару часов искал ответ. Задал вопрос. Нашёл через пару минут.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528663/django-form-pass-parameter-from-template-to-view-by-submit-button

```
<input type="hidden" name="num1" value="{{num1}}">,
```

Comment: Я может чего-то не понял, но вы и так передаёте num1 в контексте.  достаточно <input type="hidden" name="num1" value="{{num1}}">

Comment: А, ну в ответе по ссылке это и имеется в виду. Просто вы не адаптировали под свой случай. Ок.

Comment: рекомендую почитать про формы

Comment: @Alpensin исправил под свой вариант, спасибо.

Comment: @Za Ars спасибо, почитаю, только изучаю django, тяжело даётся.    А ещё не подскажете ? У меня rounds инкременченный обратно не возвращается т.е. всегда нулём остаётся, как его вернуть, чтобы инкременченное значение сохранялось ?

Comment: это другой вопрос, и их нужно создавать  отдельно. а вообще вам надо хранить это значение в бд или в объекте за пределами view. создайте новый вопрос, и кто то ответит. ну или я когда проснусь

Comment: пройдитесь по django туториалу, тупо чтобы пройти. после этого будет больше понимания что и как надо делать

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Я прошёлся по нему, потом сделал ещё один пет - проджект на джанго. Пока не особо помогло, как видите(

Comment: @a1723 рекомендую ещё здесь почитать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django